# Using the Squeeze Theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Fix any $k∈N$, and let $a_1,...,a_k$ be $k$ positive numbers. Use the Squeeze Theorem to prove that as n aproaches infinity
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} \left(\sum^k_{j=1}a^n_j\right)^{1/n}=\max(a_1,...,a_k) $$

Comment: I've LaTeXified your maths. Please make sure that this is still asking what you wanted to ask.

Comment: Yes it is, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose (it doesn't matter) that $a_1$ is $\ge a_j$ for all $j$. Then 
$$a_1^n \le \sum_{j=1}^k a_j^n \le ka_1^n.$$
Taking $n$-th roots, we get
$$a_1\le \left(\sum_{j=1}^k a_j^n\right)^{1/n} \le k^{1/n}a_1.$$
Now Squeeze, using the fact that $\lim_{n\to\infty}k^{1/n}=1$.